# Are there ontologies for the description of the look of plants?

Tags: plant-anatomy, ontology

Are there existing ontologies for the description of the look of plants?

I am looking for something formally defined giving me at least or better more information like in descriptions:

> They are mainly deciduous shrubs and trees, often with brush-like foliage, often spiny to deter grazing, and masses of small, pea-like yellow blooms which are sometimes fragrant.

which I took from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genista .

The use case is to be able to procedurally generate 3D models of them, which are not too far away from the reality as far as an ordinary person would notice.

Answer (score 2):

To transform an object in an ontology to an image of that object?  Sounds unlikely, I doubt that any botanical ontology is that developed and detailed.  It would be great if it worked.  Could be used to check the ontology.  The website https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies lists 251 biological ontologies.  There are several on specific plants or groups of plants (brassica, beet, oats) and several that might be more relevant to you: Plant Ontology, Plant Phenology Ontology, and Plant Trait Ontology,

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete solution, but a lot of what I think you want can be done with L-systems.  See for instance "The Algorithmic Beauty of Plants" (Downloadable here: http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/#abop ) See also various things to be found under the heading of Algorithmic Botany.